# preg_replace with style format issue

Tags: php

I have this text stored in my databse:

```
 <div style=\"font-family:arial black;font-size:20px;text-align:center;color:#3333ff;font-weight:700;\">testing editor</div>
```

now when trying to process it to my website editor I'm using this function:

```
function striplen($Text)
{
// strip slashes
$Text = stripslashes($Text);
// find the errors quote
$errors = array("#\r\n#", '#"#');
// find the correct self content
$corrected = array('\r\n', '');

return preg_replace($errors, $corrected, $Text);
}
```

this out put the text like this:

```
<div style=font-family:arial black;font-size:20px;text-align:center;color:#3333ff;font-weight:700;>testing editor</div>
```

as you can see the double quotes from the style tag disappeared?

any suggestions?

many thanks,

Comment: You are replacing double quotes `#"#` with an empty string `''`. What do you intend to put there?

Comment: fix the source of the problem (dont add the slashes in the first place) if your outputting to a textarea just use `htmlspecialchars()`